# Flutter - How do i save a bool value in Shared Preferences in my Flutter Project?

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean, sharedpreferences

Have been dealing with this problem for a week now.

I don't know how to save a bool value in Shared Preferences. I really need it for multiple Projects.

Can someone show me, how i save the bool value of an Checkboxlisttile in my code?

Just modify my code, please :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/material/checkbox_list_tile.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Gym',
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

//
//
//
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  _loadData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool boolValue = prefs.getBool('option');
  }

  @override
  _saveBool() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  var _test = false as bool;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          value: _test,
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              _test = !_test;
              _saveBool();
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

watched yt videos and stackoverflow posts, nothing worked.

Comment: await prefs.setBool('option', true);

Answer (score 4):

here is a sample for your answer:

```
class SharedPreference {
  static SharedPreferences? sharedPreferences;

  static Future<void> init() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  
  static void setOptionState(bool optionState) async {
    await sharedPreferences!.setBool('option', optionState);
  }

  static bool getOption() {
    return sharedPreferences!.getBool('option') ?? false;
  }
}
```

and use setter and getter where ever you need to save bool:

```
SharedPreferences.setOptionState(true);


var yourBoolean = SharedPreferences.getOption();
```

Edit: according to the exact code that you want as you said in the comment, here is what you should do. note that before these codes create the `SharedPreference` class as I said at first:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:you_project/shared_preference.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() async{
  await SharedPreference.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Gym',
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

//
//
//
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  var _test = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  _loadData() async {
    _test = SharedPreferences.getOption();
  }

  @override
  _saveBool(bool testBool) async {
    SharedPreferences.setOptionState(testBool);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          value: _test,
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              _test = !_test;
              _saveBool(_test);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

happy coding...

Comment: I'm to stupid to put that in my code usefully XD. Also i don't want no login stuff. Could you use your knowledge, so that it fits my project? pls : )

Comment: hey Locks, first of all you can write your comment in a better word and sentences. here we don't have any fight we are here to help each other

Comment: as you see I wrote that it's a sample that i've used login state in SharedPrefrence and you can change this name to what you want but the logic is the same

Comment: i've edited the answer as exact code of your project

Comment: ok, i did everything in the exact way, you said it should be done, but i get an error, when i try to launch the application. I've added the SharedPrefernce class and i dont have any project erros. Just one, when i try to start it (FlutterError - Binding has not yet been initialized. The "instance" getter on the ServicesBinding binding mixin is only available once that binding has been initialized.)

can u please try to get this simple project running on your pc and send me the code. I just really want to use shared prefernces, but its never working.
Pls help

Comment: but it"s still not working, i've done as you wrote

Comment: if it's possible for you we can have a meet on google meet to help you.

Comment: please find me on linkedin and send you a link to have a meet

Comment: hey, locks if you have not solved it yet, let me know to help you