# Google Log In resets everytime I restart the app - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, google-signin

I am using Shared Preferences to save that if I clicked on the Log in or Log Out button it should save isLoggedIn to true or false. But this only saves the fact that I have clicked the button and based of that I am logged in or logged out. So when I restart the app it doesn't remember that I am logged in. What I am doing is writing the person's Google name on the screen but when I restart the app the name is just empty '' but when I log in again the name is there. Main.dart:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await GetStorage.init();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp(isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn));
}
```

```
home: isLoggedIn ? const NavBar() : LogIn(),
```

```
onPressed: () async {
                  SharedPreferences prefs =
                      await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                  //
                  await prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);
                  //
                  controller.login();
                  //
                },
```

Another File:

```
child: Column(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 52,
              backgroundImage:
                  NetworkImage(controller.googleAccount.value?.photoUrl ?? ''),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Text(
              controller.googleAccount.value?.displayName ?? '',
              style: subHeadingStyle,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Text(
              controller.googleAccount.value?.email ?? '',
              style: subHeadingStyle,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            )
          ],
        ),
```

So the fact that it is returning '' is because it can't get the Google info (after I have restarted the app). How can I code it so that it remembers that I am logged in?

Comment: I wanna know how you are setting your data to SharedPreference, maybe you have problem is setting, please read the answer that I've done. and if you had problem again please let me know:     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444325/flutter-how-do-i-save-a-bool-value-in-shared-preferences-in-my-flutter-project/75444381#75444381

Comment: I added the `setbool` code @AmiraliEricJanani

Comment: The setbool code was always ther i just forgor to add it to the question, the shared preferences only saves the fact that you have clicked on signed in or signed out, so it doesn't actually remember that you are logged in with your acc, so no it doesn't work yet @AmiraliEricJanani

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, if is it possible we can have a meeting on google meet to see what is goin on, here is my linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/in/amirali-janani-957a611b0/ please be connect and I send a google meet link to help you.

Comment: Do you have discord, if you do add this `Tyrone#1646`

Comment: I've sent a request.

Answer (score 1):

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _login();
      },
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: color,
      ),
    ),

_login() {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setBool("login", true);
}
```

Comment: this only saves the state and doesn't actually remember the fact that you are logged in